# Pandas stored list as string, but cannot convert it back due to decimal

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, decimal

The problem:
I saved multiple pandas df as csv files, and am now trying to do different manipulations by reloading specific df (from csv). It turns out that when I saved to_csv(), the list of dictionaries associated to a specific key was stored as a string. Below is the structure of one line of the df I have stored:

```
{key1 : value1, key2 : value2, ..., key X, "[{'product':'ABC', 'quantity':1, 'price':Decimal(91.99)}, {'product':'YXZ', 'quantity':2, 'price':Decimal(11.99)}, ..]", ..}
```

Is there an easy way to convert the string associated to key X back to a list of dictionaries? I need it to be that way to that I can create a sub pd.DataFrame() to look within that specific key.

I have read about ast.literal_eval(), but it is not liking the Decimal()... All help will be much appreciated!

Comment: The `repr` of the decimal number should have been `Decimal('91.99')` - note the quotes - but in your example they're not there. Otherwise you may be able to `from decimal import Decimal')` and then `exec("data = " + the_value)` assuming the_value is the value in the dict.

Comment: As for saving the csv in the first place, string representations of basic types tend to work, and `Decimal` will work if you include the quotes, but its not generally the case. One could `pickle` the value before the save. It would be an opaque blob and only readable by python, but at least the conversion would work. Maybe JSON with hooks for the Decimal class.

Comment: @tdelaney yes sorry this is a typo on my end, Decimal() do have the quotes in them. Thanks for the input I'll take a closer look to pickle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `eval()` since `ast.literal_eval()` is not converting to `Decimal()` object just note you need to be very aware of your data with this method.
The `eval()` method will execute a given string just like the Python interpreter so it will create objects that in the given string in your case `Decimal()`.

```
val = "[{'product':'ABC', 'quantity':1, 'price':Decimal(91.99)}, {'product':'YXZ', 'quantity':2, 'price':Decimal(11.99)}"
print(eval(val))
```

Output

```
[{'product': 'ABC',
  'quantity': 1,
  'price': Decimal('91.9899999999999948840923025272786617279052734375')},
 {'product': 'YXZ',
  'quantity': 2,
  'price': Decimal('11.9900000000000002131628207280300557613372802734375')}]
```

Comment: I did a similar thing which left me wondering why the original Decimals didn't have quotes.

Comment: The string could be preprocessed with `re.sub(r"Decimal\((\d*\.\d*)\)", r"Decimal('\1')", the_value_str)`

Comment: That is a great question not sure why it's without the quotes in the original `str`.

Comment: @LeoArad my mistake for the quotes. This is very helpful thanks a lot!

Comment: You welcome, if you can mark the answer it will be very appreciated